# How to mix two colors of varying opacities together using CSS

Tags: html, css

Some thing like this website where you can pick the middle color type.

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_mixer.asp

For example, a color that mixes red and green with 80% opacity red and 20% green would come out with a color that is more red than green.

50-50 would come out with a color that is brown

and 20-80 would come out with a color more green than red.

Answer (score 0):

use a tool like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, if you move the scales and change the colours and it should work, so in your case:

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: 
http://colorzilla.com/gradient- 
editor/#f93135+21,7fe87d+100,7fe87d+100 */
background: #f93135; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f93135 21%, 
#7fe87d 100%, #7fe87d 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f93135 
21%,#7fe87d 100%,#7fe87d 100%); /* Chrome10- 
25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f93135 
21%,#7fe87d 100%,#7fe87d 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, 
Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#f93135', 
endColorstr='#7fe87d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this automatically? I want to generate different colors based on variable opacities.